# Can't display input value

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework

Trying to take user input and print calculated values

//html

```
<div class="empty">
<h5> Input Empty Total </h5>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="Enter Empties.." type="number" name="emptySeats" [(ngModel)]="emptySeats"> </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</div>

<p> {{arenaCurrent}} </p>
```

//js

```
arenaTotal: number = 1000;
emptySeats: number;
arenaCurrent: number;

constructor() {
    this.arenaCurrent = this.arenaTotal - this.emptySeats;
 }
```

arenaCurrent will print 1000 - emptySeats (user input)

Comment: Your Javascript isn't complete, can you post more, is what you've posted part of a JS object?

Comment: Use curly braces to show your calculated Values. e.g `<p>{{arenaCurrent}}</p>`. it will update automatically

Comment: Apologies, i forgot to include my curly brackets. The javascript included is all the javascript i wrote.. am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the math only once in the constructor, you probably want to make it a property. This way the template can remain unchanged but the value will update whenever either `arenaTotal` or `emptySeats` changes.

```
arenaTotal: number = 1000;
emptySeats: number;

get arenaCurrent() {
    return this.arenaTotal - this.emptySeats;
}

constructor() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use (ionChange) to display the result.

```
<div class="empty">
     <h5> Input Empty Total </h5>
      <ion-item>
      <ion-input (ionChange)="change()" placeholder="Enter Empties.." type="number" name="emptySeats"[(ngModel)]="emptySeats"> </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </div>    
    <p> {{arenaCurrent}} </p>
```

In javascript call the function change.

```
arenaTotal: number = 1000;
emptySeats: number;
arenaCurrent: number;
constructor() {}
change(){
    this.arenaCurrent = this.arenaTotal - this.emptySeats;
}
```

The above will update the result instantly when user inputs value in ion-input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this
**#emptySeats="ngModel"**  in you ion-input tag

```
<div class="empty">
<h5> Input Empty Total </h5>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="Enter Empties.." type="number" name="emptySeats" [(ngModel)]="emptySeats" #emptySeats="ngModel"> </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</div>

<p> {{arenaCurrent}} </p>
```